# Эквалайзер или визуалайзер в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, аудио

Я делаю аудио плеер в WPF. И у меня есть ellipse. Мне требуется, чтоб под бит (музыку), этот ellipse дергался.

Comment: Было бы неплохо, да. Как думаете достичь цели?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Эквалайзер" и "Визуалайзер" - разные вещи. Эквалайзер - это средство для регулирования тембра звука, а не визуализации.

Простейший визуализатор звука можно написать с использованием Core Audio API. Начиная с висты, аудиопотоки смешиваются программно внутри службы аудио и API предоставляет доступ к громкости конкретных приложений (точнее, "сессий"). Интерфейс [IAudioSessionEnumerator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/audiopolicy/nn-audiopolicy-iaudiosessionenumerator) позволяет получить список WASAPI-сессий на аудиоустройстве. Далее, нужно найти сессии своей программы и добраться до интерфейса [IAudioMeterInformation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/endpointvolume/nn-endpointvolume-iaudiometerinformation), позволяющего получить текущий уровень звука. Следующий пример кода демонстрирует изменение высоты эллипса в зависимости от значения пикового уровня звука.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Audio player" Height="350" Width="620.522">
    <Grid Margin="0,0,3.4,63.4">
        <MediaElement x:Name="media1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="148" Margin="325,29,0,0" 
                      VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="240" 
                      Source="" 
                      LoadedBehavior="Manual"/>
        <Button x:Name="bOpen" Content="Open" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="55" 
                Margin="22,190,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="70" Click="bOpen_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="bPlay" Content="Play" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="55" 
                Margin="120,190,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="70" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
        <Button x:Name="bStop" Content="Stop" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="55" Margin="212,190,0,0"
                VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="70" Click="bStop_Click"/>
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="157" Margin="20,20,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="286">
            <Ellipse x:Name="ellVisualizer" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="50" 
                      Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="256"/>
        </Grid>        

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Timers;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        IMMDeviceEnumerator deviceEnumerator=null;
        IMMDevice speakers = null; //текущее аудиоустройство
        Timer timer; //таймер для обновления UI
        uint this_pid; //идентификатор этого процесса

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            System.Diagnostics.Process pr = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess();
            using (pr)
            {
                this_pid = (uint)pr.Id;
            }

            // get default audio device
            deviceEnumerator = (IMMDeviceEnumerator)(new MMDeviceEnumerator());
            deviceEnumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(EDataFlow.eRender, ERole.eMultimedia, out speakers);

            //start UI updating timer
            timer = new Timer(100);
            timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
            timer.Enabled = true;            
        }

        private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                this.UpdateVisualizer();
            });
        }

        //считывает текущее значение уровней звука и обновляет UI
        public void UpdateVisualizer()
        {
            if (speakers == null) return;

            IAudioSessionManager2 mgr = null;
            IAudioSessionEnumerator sessionEnumerator = null;
            IAudioSessionControl ctl = null;
            IAudioSessionControl2 ctl2 = null;
            IAudioMeterInformation meter = null;

            try
            {

                // activate the session manager. we need the enumerator
                Guid IID_IAudioSessionManager2 = typeof(IAudioSessionManager2).GUID;
                object o;
                speakers.Activate(ref IID_IAudioSessionManager2, 0, IntPtr.Zero, out o);
                mgr = (IAudioSessionManager2)o;

                // enumerate sessions for on this device            
                mgr.GetSessionEnumerator(out sessionEnumerator);
                int count;
                sessionEnumerator.GetCount(out count);

                float max_val = 0.0f; //максимальное значение уровня звука для всех сессий
                int h_min = 50, h_max = 120;//макс. и мин. значение высоты для эллипса

                int hr;    
                uint pid = 0;
                float val = 0.0f;                

                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {
                    if (ctl != null) { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ctl); ctl = null; }
                    if (ctl2 != null) { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ctl2); ctl2 = null; }
                    if (meter != null) { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(meter); meter = null; }

                    //получаем WASAPI-сессию
                    hr = sessionEnumerator.GetSession(i, out ctl);
                    if (hr != 0) continue;

                    ctl2 = (IAudioSessionControl2)ctl;
                    pid = 0;
                    ctl2.GetProcessId(out pid);
                    if (pid != this_pid) continue; //интересуют только сессии текущего процесса

                    meter = (IAudioMeterInformation)ctl;
                    hr = meter.GetPeakValue(out val);//получаем уровень звука
                    if (hr != 0) { continue; }
                    if (val > max_val) max_val = val;                    

                }

                //изменяем высоту эллипса в соответствии со значением максимального уровня звука
                ellVisualizer.Height = h_min + max_val * (h_max - h_min);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), ex.GetType().ToString());
            }
            finally
            {                
                //очистка ресурсов
                if (sessionEnumerator != null) { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sessionEnumerator); sessionEnumerator = null; }
                if (mgr != null) { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mgr); mgr = null; }

                if (ctl != null) { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ctl); ctl = null; }
                if (ctl2 != null) { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ctl2); ctl2 = null; }
                if (meter != null) { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(meter); meter = null; }
            }


        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            media1.Play();
        }

        private void bStop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            media1.Stop();
        }

        private void bOpen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog ofd = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.DefaultExt = "mp3";
            ofd.Filter = "Audio files (WAV,MP3,WMA)|*.wav;*.mp3;*.wma|All files|*.*";
            var res = ofd.ShowDialog(this);
            if (res.HasValue)
            {
                if (res.Value != false)
                {
                    media1.Source = new Uri(ofd.FileName);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // *** COM Objects declarations ***
    [ComImport]
    [Guid("BCDE0395-E52F-467C-8E3D-C4579291692E")]
    internal class MMDeviceEnumerator
    {
    }

    internal enum EDataFlow
    {
        eRender,
        eCapture,
        eAll,
        EDataFlow_enum_count
    }

    internal enum ERole
    {
        eConsole,
        eMultimedia,
        eCommunications,
        ERole_enum_count
    }

    [Guid("A95664D2-9614-4F35-A746-DE8DB63617E6"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    internal interface IMMDeviceEnumerator
    {
        int NotImpl1();

        [PreserveSig]
        int GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(EDataFlow dataFlow, ERole role, out IMMDevice ppDevice);

        // the rest is not implemented
    }

    [Guid("D666063F-1587-4E43-81F1-B948E807363F"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    internal interface IMMDevice
    {
        [PreserveSig]
        int Activate(ref Guid iid, int dwClsCtx, IntPtr pActivationParams, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] out object ppInterface);

        // the rest is not implemented
    }

    [Guid("77AA99A0-1BD6-484F-8BC7-2C654C9A9B6F"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    internal interface IAudioSessionManager2
    {
        int NotImpl1();
        int NotImpl2();

        [PreserveSig]
        int GetSessionEnumerator(out IAudioSessionEnumerator SessionEnum);

        // the rest is not implemented
    }

    [Guid("E2F5BB11-0570-40CA-ACDD-3AA01277DEE8"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    internal interface IAudioSessionEnumerator
    {
        [PreserveSig]
        int GetCount(out int SessionCount);

        [PreserveSig]
        int GetSession(int SessionCount, out IAudioSessionControl Session);
    }

    [Guid("F4B1A599-7266-4319-A8CA-E70ACB11E8CD"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    internal interface IAudioSessionControl
    {
        int NotImpl1();

        [PreserveSig]
        int GetDisplayName([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] out string pRetVal);

        // the rest is not implemented
    }

    //Источник: https://github.com/maindefine/volumecontrol/blob/master/C%23/CoreAudioApi/Interfaces/IAudioSessionControl2.cs
        [Guid("bfb7ff88-7239-4fc9-8fa2-07c950be9c6d"),
     InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    interface IAudioSessionControl2
    {
        //IAudioSession functions
        [PreserveSig]
        int GetState(out object state);
        [PreserveSig]
        int GetDisplayName(out IntPtr name);
        [PreserveSig]
        int SetDisplayName(string value, Guid EventContext);
        [PreserveSig]
        int GetIconPath(out IntPtr Path);
        [PreserveSig]
        int SetIconPath(string Value, Guid EventContext);
        [PreserveSig]
        int GetGroupingParam(out Guid GroupingParam);
        [PreserveSig]
        int SetGroupingParam(Guid Override, Guid Eventcontext);
        [PreserveSig]
        int RegisterAudioSessionNotification(object NewNotifications);
        [PreserveSig]
        int UnregisterAudioSessionNotification(object NewNotifications);
        //IAudioSession2 functions
        [PreserveSig]
        int GetSessionIdentifier( out IntPtr retVal);
        [PreserveSig]
        int GetSessionInstanceIdentifier( out IntPtr retVal);
        [PreserveSig]
        int GetProcessId( out UInt32 retvVal);
        [PreserveSig]
        int IsSystemSoundsSession();
        [PreserveSig]
        int SetDuckingPreference( bool optOut);


    }

    //Источник: https://github.com/maindefine/volumecontrol/blob/master/C%23/CoreAudioApi/Interfaces/IAudioMeterInformation.cs
    [Guid("C02216F6-8C67-4B5B-9D00-D008E73E0064"),
     InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    internal interface IAudioMeterInformation 
    {
        [PreserveSig]
        int GetPeakValue(out float pfPeak);
        [PreserveSig]
        int GetMeteringChannelCount(out int pnChannelCount);
        [PreserveSig]
        int GetChannelsPeakValues( int u32ChannelCount,[In]   IntPtr afPeakValues);
        [PreserveSig]
        int QueryHardwareSupport( out int pdwHardwareSupportMask);
    };
}
```

Источники:

[C# Управление звуком приложения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/586898/c-%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

[Peak meters for individual programs on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14367829/8674428)

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { this.UpdateVisualizer(); }));
    }
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]