# Как узнать уровень громкости воспроизводимых звуков в Windows?

Tags: windows, аудио

Мне необходимо узнать уровень громкости воспроизводимых звуков в Windows. НЕ УРОВЕНЬ ГРОМКОСТИ, а именно уровень текущего звука. На микшере в Windows 7 этот уровень обозначен зеленой шкалой. Есть идеи?

Comment: Скачай программу Volume, это замена стандартному регулятору громкости в вин7

Comment: И ещё советую перейти с 7-ки на 10-ку^^

Comment: А если выход с устройства цифровой: SPDIF, протокол HDMI или иной? То громкость в воплях попугаев измерять?

Comment: А что значит в данном случае "узнать"? Числом вывести? В децибелах, или в процентах от максимума? Программно, из скрипта, или просто так?

Comment: @СултанГордов Речь об этой программе: https://www.softportal.com/software-18603-volume2.html ? Как именно с помощью нее узнать уровень громкости? Возможно, стоит дополнить ответ.

Comment: А это абсолютно не принципиально в чем. Мне достаточно знать, что он отличается от 0

Comment: Программно это делается через метод  [IAudioMeterInformation::GetPeakValue](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/endpointvolume/nf-endpointvolume-iaudiometerinformation-getpeakvalue) Core Audio API. Примеры: [для отдельных приложений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/860315/), [для  устройства в целом](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/peak-meters).